# multi select mysql node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to make multiples select from different tables in mysql, but i dont know how to resolve this with nodejs,

first query:

```
SELECT id1,value1,value2 FROM table
```

my second query:

```
SELECT newvalue1,newvalue2 FROM table2 WHERE id=id1
```

I need make a json array with the data of the first query and add to the value3 the result of the second query:

```
json_array = [{value1,value2,value3:[{newvalue1,newvalue2}]}]
```

I'm trying with async, but i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

reading a little more and testing i find the solution using the function map of async:

example:

```
mysql_connection.query(query,function(error,rows){
    async.map(rows,processRow,function(error_map,final_result){
        //code here for end of mapping
    });
});

function processRow(row,callback){
    mysql_connection.query(query,function(error,newdata){
            row.newdata = newdata;
            callback(null,row);
    });
}
```

documentation: https://github.com/caolan/async#map